# AVAudioPlayer works once

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Trying to create a playlist of music files that are NOT part of the user's iphone library so I'm using `AVAudioPlayer` and creating the playlist functionality myself.  It works on the first pass (meaning the first song is played).  When the first song finishes and it goes to play the 2nd `AVAudioPlayer` crashes in `prepareToPlay`.

```
- (void) create {
    Song *song;

    NSArray *parts;
    NSString *path;
    NSString *name;  
    NSError *err;

    if (currentIndex > [queue count])
        currentIndex = 0;
    if (currentIndex < 0)
        currentIndex = ([queue count] - 1);

    song = (Song *) [queue objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
    name = song.fileName;
    parts = [name componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[parts objectAtIndex:0] ofType:[parts objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &err];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &err];

    appPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url error: &err];

    [url release];
    [parts release];

    [appPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [appPlayer setVolume: 1.0];
    [appPlayer setDelegate: self];
}

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL) flag { 
    [appPlayer stop];
    [appPlayer release];
    appPlayer = nil;

    [self next];
}
```

The call to `[self next]` just increases `currentIndex` and calls create again.

The only other thing (I know, the infamous "only other thing" statement) is that this is all going on inside a Singleton.  There's lots of things that could cause the music to start and stop playing, change the queue, etc so I thought it would be best to wrap it all up in one spot.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Open the debugger window, and investigate the stack trace and the specific crash identifier: a raised exception versus EXC_BAD_ACCESS versus something else. While debugging, you can also mouse over your source to investigate the values of your variables at crash-time. There's more you can do to diagnose the problem than to just throw your code on Stack Overflow and say "it crashes".

Comment: Except for the fact that the debugger shows everything is fine, variables have what appear to be proper values, and I don't get a stack trace but a hard crash ... your comment was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to track this down myself.  I re-wrote the whole section to have multiple AVAudioPlayer objects but still had issues.  Turns out the [parts release] line was the issue, it was causing an over-release situation in the autorelease routine.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason of having exception in `prepareToPlay` method is enabled "All Exceptions" breakpoint. Go to Breakpoint Navigator and disable it.